# Don't render SVG element with definitions only

Tags: html, svg, html-head

I'd like to have one `<svg>` tag in my page that includes all my SVG definitions that I'll be using on other SVG elements.
Something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow1">
            <feDropShadow dx="3" dy="7" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

</head>
<body style="display: flex">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100">
        <path d="M0,0 L50,50" stroke="red" filter="url(#shadow1)" />
    </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

This works, but the problem is that the browser renders the `<svg>` tag that's in the `<head>` as if it was inside the body.

If I set `width=0` and `height=0` on the `<svg>` tag, it disappears but it's still a child element of the `<body>`.

Is it possible to have an `<svg>` tag with definitions only but outside the page's `<body>`?

Or a least some way of telling the browser that the `<svg>` element is purely declaratory and not meant to be part of the visible area of the document.

**P.S.:** I don't want to use and external .svg file because the definitions inside are dynamic and depend on the page being viewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [SVGElement (`<svg>`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement) is not part of the [meta-data contents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#metadata-content-2), only content-type allowed in [`<head>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element). It must be a descendant of the `<body>`.

But you can place it absolutely with CSS, set its z-index to -1, set its size attributes to 0 and it would not be rendered.

```css
svg.defs {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="defs">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow1">
      <feDropShadow dx="3" dy="7" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100">
  <path d="M0,0 L50,50" stroke="red" filter="url(#shadow1)" />
</svg>
```